# Laravel 4 PHP redirect header

Tags: php, laravel-4

How can I do PHP redirect header in Laravel 4?

In original PHP:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

I don't want to do with `return Redirect::route('loginpage');`. Because it does not work well with ajax. So, how can I do the PHP redirect with Laravel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to get the url and refresh the page with an ajax function you could simply return the laravel route url and refresh the page with javascript:

```
// Use the route helper function
return route('loginpage');

// Javascript page redirect
var url = 'Your ajax response here';
window.location.href = url;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return Redirect::to('loginpage')
```

Is the most common way. Why doesn't that work well with ajax?

Comment: Because that will show the login page in the ajax div. What I want is it will turn the whole page to login page.

Answer (score 0):

When using AJAX, your request isn't handled the way you're expecting it to be. This isn't a laravel-specific issue, as your header() location example would not work either.

If you want to make an ajax request that redirects the user, you'll need to have the response from ajax return something that you can key off of in javascript that executes a window.location change based on the results.